# Does the frozen biome itself provide cooling?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

The [frozen biomes](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Biome#Frozen_Biome) are great places to cool things down, which is a constant challenge in the game and requirement for [Sleet Wheat](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Sleet_Wheat).  Usually there is a lot of [liquifiable](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Category:Liquifiable) and cool frozen water and [polluted water](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Polluted_Water) in these biomes. Often one way or another all the frozen ice in a frozen biome eventually melts from exposure to heat from different sources and digging.  That leaves me wondering if the biome loses its cooling ability after everything has melted, besides any thermo-nullifers that might be there.

[image: Frozen biome]
I once tried to melt a frozen biome with the redirected output from a cool steam vent but it didn't seem to make much progress in consistently warming even a small part of the frozen biome.

Does the frozen biome cause any cooling by itself or is any cooling the result of the frozen resources within it only?

If it does cause cooling, how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that would 'produce' cooling is the wheezeworts. I don't see any in your picture, maybe because you already dug them up.

https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Biome says that no biomes have special properties that keep them cool or hot, merely their starting temperatures.
I think what is happening is that there is a lot of tiles to soak up added heat.  If you want to melt the frozen biome, try digging out the abyssalite separating it from a hot biome.  Or save it for pumping to your base for cooling.

Comment: +1 I did remove the abyssalite before I tried to melt the frozen biome, but it didn't seem to work.  However, I do have a hotwater geyser in my current game that may melt a large part of the biome eventually, so I may find out for sure.